# Почему Virtual Box не сохраняет изменения?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, alpine-linux

Почему Virtual Box не сохраняет изменения?
Пытаюсь запустить виртуальный alpinelinux, делаю setup-alpine, все норм отрабатывает.
Перезапускаю машину, все откатывается к началу.
В чем причина такого явления?
P.S. Опыта работы с VirtualBox нету

Comment: Значит вы делаете что-то чудовищно странное, потому что виртуалбокс по умолчанию все изменения на диске вполне сохраняет

Comment: И по каким признакам вы определили, что всё откатывается к началу?

Comment: @andreymal, в оси я ставлю nano командой "apk add nano", проверяю, запускается. перезагружаю - нужно устанавливать заново.

Comment: А где у вас расположена ось? Вы точно грузитесь не с установочного диска?

Comment: @andreymal, как отключить загрузочный диск?

Comment: Так же, как вы его включили перед установкой оси, очевидно

Comment: @andreymal, да, при запуске машины окно попросило образ. как его выключить?

Comment: Зайдите в настройки виртуальной машины хотя бы разок и немного полазайте — сразу увидите)

Comment: @andreymal, отключил. выставил жесткий диск первым для загрузки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

отключил загрузочный диск, выставил жесткий диск первым для загрузки, все заработало.